# jQuery Mobile fixed header div overlaps content div

Tags: jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

Am using Jquery Mobile 1.3.1 on Worklight 6. When I use a fixed header and content. The header always seem to overlap the content. Please suggest what I am doing wrong.

```
<body id="content" style="display: none;">
    <div data-role="page" id="basic">
        <div data-role ="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h3>CORS</h3>
        </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <form id="basic-information">
            <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="c" data-content-theme="d" data-inset="false">
                <div data-role="collapsible">
                    <h3>Basic Information</h3>
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"
                    data-mini="true">
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what's up with jQuery Mobile, but it seems to originate from there (tested with jQuery Mobile 1.4.2, happens there as well).

To fix, I have added the following to common\css\main.css:

```
.ui-page-header-fixed { padding-top: 15px !important; }
```

BTW,
Your code snippet is cut... (not full).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that fixed it for me, about the code not being full, I intentionally did not add it as the accordion was pretty big and I was not sure if adding the whole thing would be pretty useful as my problem was only wit the Header.

Comment: Has anyone looked at this further?  When I look at the .ui-page-header-fixed doesn't fix the problem.  It might fix the header/content overlap initially, but when the device is rotated and then rotated back, we now have "extra" padding on our page.  I used to force a trigger a resize: $(window).on('load', function () {
    $(this).trigger('resize');
});  but this no longer appears to work with the latest MFP V7.  Thanks!